# JPA schema file for two databases

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have two datasources (JPA) in my project. Both are on hsql server. I need to recreate the schema each time. For the first datasource I have schema-hsql.sql and import.sql files. Where to put initial HSQL script for second datasource?

My datasources configuration is based on http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

In this since it is a special case where two `DataSource`s are available you can not use the default way of creating tables and inserting initial data using `schema-hsql.sql` and `import.sql`.

In this case you need to do some programming using [DatabasePopulatorUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/DatabasePopulatorUtils.html)

```
DataSource dataSource1() { ... }

DataSource dataSource2() { ... }

DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(new ResourceDatabasePopulater(new ClasspathResource("schema-datasource1.sql"), new ClasspathResource("import-datasource1.sql")), dataSource1());

DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(new ResourceDatabasePopulater(new ClasspathResource("schema-datasource2.sql"), new ClasspathResource("import-datasource2.sql")), dataSource2());
```